# Require JS callback argument undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

First off, I'm pretty new to Require JS, and I haven't done my fair share of reading the docs. Kind of just shooting from the hip here.

But this is functionality that, should work. Well as far as I've read.

I have a hashed URL, say at this stage it's `#index`.
And then I have the equivalent js page under `/javascript/pages/index.js`.

As you would figure, I'm trying to load these pages "dynamically".
However, my callback functions page parameter is undefined.

```
require(['javascript/pages/' + page],
    function(page) {
        var constructedPage = new page();
    });
```

All Pages are "classes" `function index(){}`

In the meanwhile, I'll start reading up on the docs a bit more.

Comment: The `index.js` includes a correct `define()` call?

Comment: Well no, do I need to include a define call? The page I'm loading isn't a dependency of another. Nothing will depend on either of these pages. They're quite standalone.

Comment: If you want to refer to the object returned via `new page()` as in your example, you have to use `define()`.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a go quick. Post an answer though, so I can vote it up :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use objects/variables/etc created in the `index.js` within the callback of `require()`, you have to use a `define()` call to specify that object.

**index.js**

```
define(function(){

  // create an object with constructor
  function myPage(){
  }

  // some more code adding to the prototype

  // return the actual object
  return myPage;

});
```

Then you can use that object like you did in your code.

Note: That `define()` call may have dependencies of its own. Omitted here for simplicity's sake.